# should I sell some stocks?

Tags: selling

I am 80yo and have some great stocks with dividends which is great but most without dividends. I need to remodel my home and was wondering if it would be sensible at this point in my life to sell about $50,000.00 to enable me to enjoy my home. The total value of my stocks are 200K so would not be selling them all. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you didn’t sell the stock, how else might you get the $50,000 you need to remodel? What other options are you considering?

Comment: Are any of these essential repairs? Is there a possibility of future repairs like a roof, etc.? Are you desperate to redo the house or is someone else wanting it done?

Comment: sorry meant 200K. I do have bank savings I could use but at my age it seems like I should use some of that money sitting in stocks by selling some stocks vs taking it out of my savings

Comment: I might be concerned about the stock losing value that you won't live long enough to see it recover. My understanding is that at your age, you would want your assets in something less volatile that minimize the risk of loss, at the expense of additional growth.

Answer (score -1):

If the house is remodeled with a home-equity loan then if something goes wrong in the world it's possible to just walk off. The bank can only repossess the house, the bank can't get the stock investments.

But if only 1/4 of the stocks are sold then that is reasonable unless there are significant capital gains taxes.

Comment: *"The bank can only repossess the house, the bank can't get the stock investments."* That would depend on the jurisdiction.